# Having large lists in main scripts, is there anyway to get it out of the main-script and into another module?

Tags: python, list, class, python-3.x, module

I'm working on a program where you can choose between different categories and each category have certain questions, let's say around 10 questions for each caterogry.

I'm planning on having all the questions in lists, one list for every category, containing their specific questions. Then in the main script I call the question and I want and the user gets to choose between 4 different answers where one is the correct answer.

I'm wondering if you can get the code out of the main script and wrapp in in a class maybe?

The only thing I know how to do at the moment is just have the questions in my main script like this for example:

```
sports_questions = ["What sport did michael jordan play?", "blablalba?", "and so on"]
computer_questions = ["Who founded microsoft?", "blabla", "many questions"]
```

But is there anyway I can get it out of my main script and into another module, like a  class or something? If so, can someone explain to me how it's done?

At this moment all I can think of is like this for example:

```
class Sports():
    def __init__(self):
        self.questions = []

    def sports_questions(self):
        self.questions = []

    def __str__():
        return self.questions + " "
```

and in main script (example):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    gp = sports()

    gp.questions = ["Which sport did micheal jordan played?", "blablabla"]
```

But this would still doesn't solve my problem because the code is still in the main script.

Comment: Short short answer: yes.

Comment: In other words, why don't you *try this out* and tell us what problems you ran into?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm not sure how to wrapp it in a class without still having the questions in my main script. At the moment I only have the knowledge to store a list in the class and then call the list from the class in my main script and put the questions in the correct class list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a file `questions.py`:

```
sports_questions = ["What sport did michael jordan play?", "blablalba?", "and so on"]
computer_questions = ["Who founded microsoft?", "blabla", "many questions"]
```

And then make your main module (e. g. the file `quiz.py`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import questions

print "question one is,", questions.sports_questions[0]
```

Does this make it clear how to refactor your questions into another module?

Comment: Yes this works just like I wanted. Didn't know it was this easy to do it hehe :) Thank you very much!

Comment: That's why Python is so addictive ;-)